# What's the difference between 可 and 可以?

Tags: difference, synonyms

I've seen threads for 可以 as opposed to 会 and 能, but what about 可以 with its component, 可?

Wiktionary seems to use them interchangeably:
白银**可以**指：银，贵金属，用做货币时**可**称为白银

Is there a difference in nuance, or flow of the sentence?

Comment: see dictionaries and Chinese grammars, e.g. iciba for 可（可以 is discussed in Chinese grammars in the section on 能愿动词）in addition to answer below note, 可 used to form adjectives: 可爱、可悲、可靠 lovable, lamentable, reliable, 连 （表示转折） but; yet (可是）；副 about  年可80,重可百斤

Comment: 可 is the original verb. 以 is a void suffix that has been added for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"可" is a morpheme, while "可以" is a word.

With the meaning of "be able to", "可" and "可以" are interchangeable in most cases.

When we answer a question, we should say "可以", which means "fine", or "OK". When coming to popular culture, some of us would just answer "可", which is not literally supposed to. Say, if you answer like this, we could still understand.

Here are the situations I could come up with, only "可" is used as emphatic adverb (just like "very"), sometimes used to throw a question.
See definition #2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%AF)

- For example, "这本书可贵了", which means "this book is very expensive". This is the morpheme "可" used for emphasis.
- Another example, "近来可好？", which means "How have you been recently?". This is the morpheme "可" used to throw a question.

Comment: Hi S1ngS1ng, thank you for your contribution! It would be better if you add some reference :D

Comment: @congliu Hi. Sure I will. Though I only found one ref. Others are based on personal experience.

Comment: 多谢！您的回复可详了！
(Did I use it right?)

Comment: @JAF Ha! I understand what you wanna say. But please keep that in mind, "详" is a morpheme, which means you could have multiple words with it. Such as “详细”，“详实”， “安祥”， “慈祥”. In your case, you might mean "详细". It should be better to say "您的回复可详细了", or "您的回复很详细". Personally, I would say "您的回复很有帮助", which means "your reply is very helpful". That is probably a better way to express your feeling. What do you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

"可以" simply means can, be able to.
"可" means a lot than that, but is rarely used alone. It's wired that you say 可 to some questions. But it's ok to use like that, and when it happens, it has the same meaning as 可以, but it feels like u are a king.... Anyway it is really wired.
when 可 is used with other character, it usually emphasis that char.